# how to build UML (user mode linux) in 32 bit mode on 64-bit host

Tags: linux, kernel

I am trying to build UML (User Mode Linux) kernel in 32-bit on a 64-bit linux host. How can I do that?

I was able to build UML kernel in 64-bit like following:

```
make defconfig ARCH=um
make ARCH=um
```

The UML kernel source tree is linux 2.6.27.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try make with `ARCH=um SUBARCH=i386`